# position span element as appended to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a little ascii ski free game... throwback to the Win95 game.

For some reason, appended obstacle spans are being clumped to one side, despite me setting position absolute and left to a random coordinate.

[image]

Here's how it should look (spans are randomly distributed):

[image]

Here is my code snippet that generates the obstacles at an interval and assigns absolute positioning and left positioning:

```
function objectFactory() {

var randObj = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1),
            randX = Math.floor((Math.random()*700)+1),
            randY = Math.floor((Math.random()*400)+1);

$('#myObstacles').append("<span id=\"" + randX + "\">" + items[randObj] + "</span>");

document.getElementById(randX).style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById(randX).style.left = randX;
document.getElementById(randX).style.top = 500;
console.log(document.getElementById(randX).style.left);
}
```

The appended divs are not being assigned a `left` position:

[image]

Here's how it should look:

[image]

And, `console.log(document.getElementById(randX).style.left);` doesn't display anything.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the units when assigning to `.style.left` and `.style.top`:

```
document.getElementById(randX).style.left = randX + "px";
document.getElementById(randX).style.top = "500px";
```

(Normally I would say "Or as you're using jQuery" followed by an example with a selector, but `id` selectors starting with digits are a PITA...)

But separately: What if two (or more) of your randomly-created obstacles are in the same `randX` position? You'll end up creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid.

Instead, just work directly with the objects:

```
function objectFactory() {
    var randObj  = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1),
        randX    = Math.floor((Math.random()*700)+1),
        randY    = Math.floor((Math.random()*400)+1),
        obstacle = $("<span id=\"" + id + "\">" + items[randObj] + "</span>");

    obstacle.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left:     randX,
        top:      500
    }).appendTo("#myObstacles");

}
```

Side note: Whenever you find yourself assigning static style information to a lot of elements (`position: absolute`, `top: 500px`), it's worth looking at whether to use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks TJ! oops noob mistake